# Inno Setup create array from comma delimited strings stored in an array

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to create an array from a number of comma delimited strings which are stored in an array themselves. The master array which contains the list of comma delimited strings is `RemoteSiteLines` and can contain any number of string entries like `1001,Remote Site 1,REM1,0`, `1002,Remote Site 2,REM2,1` etc. which I need to get into another array `RemoteSiteDetailsLines`.

I am struggling to know even where to start with this and unless I am mistaken there are no built-in functions to do something like this in Inno Setup. Can anyone suggest a procedure for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a two-dimensional array like `array of array of string`.

Parsing can be done like below. It's not the most efficient code, but it's relatively simple and short.

```pascal
procedure ParseArray(Lines: array of string; var Tokens: array of array of string);
var
  Count, Index, Index2, P: Integer;
  Line: string;
begin
  Count := GetArrayLength(Lines);
  { Allocate target array }
  SetArrayLength(Tokens, Count);

  { Iterate lines }
  for Index := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    Line := Lines[Index];
    Log(Format('Line[%d]: %s', [Index, Line]));
    
    Index2 := 0;
    { Loop until we consume whole line }
    while Line <> '' do
    begin
      { Look for the next delimiter }
      P := Pos(',', Line);
      { Reallocate array to fit yet another token }
      SetArrayLength(Tokens[Index], Index2 + 1);
      if P > 0 then
      begin
        { Copy the token to the target array }
        Tokens[Index][Index2] := Copy(Line, 1, P - 1);
        { Remove the token and the delimiter from the string, }
        { so that we can look for the next token in the next iteration }
        Delete(Line, 1, P);
      end
        else
      begin
        Tokens[Index][Index2] := Line;
        { Got last token, break the loop }
        Line := '';
      end;

      Log(Format('Token[%d][%d]: %s', [Index, Index2, Tokens[Index][Index2]]));
      Inc(Index2);
    end;
  end;
end;
    
{ Usage example }
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  RemoteSiteLines: array of string;
  RemoteSiteDetailsLines: array of array of string;
begin
  SetArrayLength(RemoteSiteLines, 3);
  RemoteSiteLines[0] := '1001,Remote Site 1,REM1,0';
  RemoteSiteLines[1] := '1002,Remote Site 2,REM2,0';
  RemoteSiteLines[2] := '1003,Remote Site 3,REM3,0';
  ParseArray(RemoteSiteLines, RemoteSiteDetailsLines);
end;
```

The result will be like:

```
Line[0]: 1001,Remote Site 1,REM1,0
Token[0][0]: 1001
Token[0][1]: Remote Site 1
Token[0][2]: REM1
Token[0][3]: 0
Line[1]: 1002,Remote Site 2,REM2,0
Token[1][0]: 1002
Token[1][1]: Remote Site 2
Token[1][2]: REM2
Token[1][3]: 0
Line[2]: 1003,Remote Site 3,REM3,0
Token[2][0]: 1003
Token[2][1]: Remote Site 3
Token[2][2]: REM3
Token[2][3]: 0
```