# Inno Setup convert string in array to boolean

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Following on from [Inno Setup create array from comma delimited strings stored in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722161/inno-setup-create-array-from-comma-delimited-strings-stored-in-an-array), I have a two dimensional (four column) array `RemoteDetailsLines`, in which the last column stores a `1` or `0` indicating whether it is active or not. I want to create a `CheckListBox` using the values from the array as below, which works fine for creating and naming the checkboxes, but I also want to have the box appear checked where the last column contains a `1`. Using `RemoteDetailsLines[intIndex][3]` where it appears in the code below does not work, even if I use `StringChangeEx` to loop through and convert the `1` and `0` values to `True` and `False`, as the values are strings.

Therefore, the question is how can these values be converted to a `Boolean` that the `AddCheckBox` function is expecting? I am not even sure if arrays can be anything other than string values?

```pascal
CheckListBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(SelectRemotesPage);
with CheckListBox do
  begin       
    Parent := SelectRemotesPage.Surface;          
    Left := ScaleX(0);
    Top := ScaleY(50);
    Width := ScaleX(250);
    Height := ScaleY(153);
    for intIndex := 0 to intNumberRemotes - 1 do
      begin
        AddCheckBox(RemoteDetailsLines[intIndex][1], RemoteDetailsLines[intIndex][2], 0, RemoteDetailsLines[intIndex][3], True, False, False, Nil);
      end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this simple case it's enough to use:

```pascal
AddCheckBox(..., (RemoteDetailsLines[intIndex][3] <> '0'), ...);
```

The comparison operator `<>` returns `Boolean`.

---

A more robust solution is:

```pascal
AddCheckBox(..., (StrToIntDef(RemoteDetailsLines[intIndex][3], 0) <> 0), ...);
```

Convert the string to an `Integer` with a fallback to `0` and then compare the integer to `0`.

Comment: Thanks, such a simple solution! I was looking for something far more complicated. and trying to change it in the array beforehand. Sometimes the longer you look at something, the harder it is to separate the wood from the trees.